# ¿Cómo unificar dos registros de una consulta SQL en uno solo?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

mi duda es la siguiente

Tengo una consulta así:

```
SELECT P.fecha, D.id_partido, E.nombre equipo1, P.ptos_local, E.nombre equipo2, P.ptos_visitante
FROM Disputan D
JOIN Equipo E ON D.id_equipo = E.id_equipo
JOIN Partido P ON D.id_partido = P.id_partido
WHERE P.id_deporte = 1;
```

Las tablas son éstas: (por si quieren copiar y pegar)

```
/* Usuario */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Usuario (
ci INTEGER not null,
clave VARCHAR(20) not null,
nombre VARCHAR(20) not null,
apellido VARCHAR(20) not null,
correo VARCHAR(319) not null,    
fecha_nacimiento DATE not null,
PRIMARY KEY (ci)
);

/* Partido*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Partido (
id_partido SMALLINT not null auto_increment,
fecha DATE not null,
ptos_local SMALLINT,
ptos_visitante SMALLINT,
id_deporte SMALLINT,
PRIMARY KEY (id_partido)
);

/* Equipo*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Equipo (
id_equipo SMALLINT not null auto_increment,
nombre VARCHAR(40) not null,
categoria SMALLINT not null,
id_deporte SMALLINT,
ci INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (id_equipo)
);

/* Disputan */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Disputan (
id_partido SMALLINT,
id_equipo SMALLINT,
PRIMARY KEY (id_partido, id_equipo)
);

ALTER TABLE Partido ADD (
CONSTRAINT fk_id_deporte_partido FOREIGN KEY (id_deporte) REFERENCES Deporte (id_deporte)
);

ALTER TABLE Equipo ADD (
CONSTRAINT fk_id_deporte_equipo FOREIGN KEY (id_deporte) REFERENCES Deporte (id_deporte),
CONSTRAINT fk_ci_equipo FOREIGN KEY (ci) REFERENCES Usuario (ci)
);

ALTER TABLE Disputan ADD (
CONSTRAINT fk_id_partido_disputan FOREIGN KEY (id_partido) REFERENCES Partido (id_partido),
CONSTRAINT fk_id_equipo_disputan FOREIGN KEY (id_equipo) REFERENCES Equipo (id_equipo)
);
```

Y muestra algo así:

| Fecha | ID | Local | Goles | Visitante | Goles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-05 | 1 | Equipo1 | 1 | Equipo1 | 0 |
| 2022-11-05 | 1 | Equipo2 | 1 | Equipo2 | 0 |

Yo quiero que muestre esto:

| Fecha | ID | Local | Goles | Visitante | Goles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-05 | 1 | Equipo1 | 1 | Equipo2 | 0 |

¿Tienen idea como podría hacer?

Intenté con MAX y MIN en equipo1 y equipo2, pero, cuando tenía varios partidos de los mismos equipos me mostraba sólo uno.

Gracias!

Comment: group by D.id_partido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La Base de datos esta mal diseñada porque es imposible sabe quien fue el local y quien el visitante

La tabla Disputan no debería existir y crear dos campos nuevos en Partido con los ides de equipo visitante y otro de local

Podrías intentar algo así para salir del paso (usando subselect para cada nombre de equipo) suponiendo que el primero en la tabla es el local:

```
**SELECT 
P.fecha, 
P.id_partido, 
(SELECT  top 1 nombre 
FROM Disputan D
JOIN Equipo E ON D.id_equipo = E.id_equipo
where D.id_partido = P.id_partido) equipo1,
 P.ptos_local, 
(SELECT  top 1 nombre 
FROM Disputan D
JOIN Equipo E ON D.id_equipo = E.id_equipo
where D.id_partido = P.id_partido and equipo1<>nombre) equipo2,
 P.ptos_visitante
FROM Partido P 

WHERE P.id_deporte = 1;**
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! es que nos dieron este DER (https://i.imgur.com/ILXx7R7.png) y tendríamos que hacer las consultas para mostrarlo con PHP, no sé bien si podría cambiar algo para mejorarlo.